# Can I trigger a onclick event in a function component which updates the state of a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, setstate

I am trying to create some Navbar dropdown buttons, I have dynamically added the buttons and I am trying to add the onclick event which just toggles the selected button/item/Object in Section array from state through setState.
I have tried almost everything I could look up from internet and the errors keep popping.
If anyone could suggest a solution, that would be a big help.
Cheers

```
import './Intro.css'
import{Dropdown} from 'react-bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
var Introbar_=class IntroBar extends Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);      
        this.state = { Sections:[{name:'Subject',open:false},{name:'Partner',open:false},{name:'Program',open:false},{name:'Level',open:false},{name:'Availability',open:false},{name:'Language',open:false}],Filters:['Courses','Programs','All']}   
 }
   
    OnbuttonClick=(item)=>e=>{
        console.log(item) 
       return( this.setState(item=>({
      
           item:!item.open
        }))  
    )
    }
    render() { 
        
      
        return ( 
            <div className="Intro-Container">
                <Bg/>
                <SearchBar/>
                <DisplaySections param={this.state.Sections}  onClick={this.OnbuttonClick}/*stateparam={this.state.open} Action={this.handleButtonClick}*//>
                <DisplayFilters param={this.state.Filters} />
            </div>
         );
    }
}
function DisplayFilters(params)
{
    let arr= params.param;
    return(
        <div className="Filter-options">{
        arr.map((item)=>(Filter(item)))
         } </div>
    );
}
function Filter(params) {
    return(
        <button className="Filter">
        {params}
         </button>
    )
    
}
function DisplaySections(params)
{
    let arr=params.param;
    return(
        <div className="Section-options">
           { arr.map((item)=>(Section(item,params.onClick)))}
        </div>
    );
}
function Section(item,onClick)
{
    let arj=item;
    return(
    <button className="Section" onClick={(item)=>onClick(item)}>
        {item.name}
        {console.log(item.name + "Before click " +item.open)}
        {item.open && (CallAddDrop(item.name))}
    </button>
    );
}
function Bg(params) {
    return(
    <div className="Bg">

    </div>
    );
}
function SearchBar(params) {
    return(
    <div>
        <form class="Search-bar">
            <p class="Form-text">Search Courses and Programs</p>
            <input className="input" type="text" value="Computer Science"></input>
            <button class="Button">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    );
}

function CallAddDrop(params)
{
    return ( 
         <div>
             <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">{params}</Dropdown.Item>
         </div>
          
      );

}
 
export default Introbar_;
```

Comment: `window.global.OnbuttonClick`? Where did this come from?

Comment: I added this in constructor of my original code. Tried to make it global function so it might be accessible in the functional component.

Comment: @CuriousBoy. I have added a way you could do this. Check if might work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use props to achieve this in React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class IntroBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);      
    this.state = { Sections:[{name:'Subject',open:false},{name:'Partner',open:false},{name:'Program',open:false},{name:'Level',open:false},{name:'Availability',open:false},{name:'Language',open:false}]}   


    OnbuttonClick = item => {
        console.log(item) 
        this.setState(previousState => ({
            Sections: previousState.Sections.map((section) => {
                if (section.name == item.name) return { name: item.name, open: !item.open };
                else return section;
            }),
        }))  
    )

    render() { 
         return ( 
            <div className="Intro-Container">
                <DisplaySections param={this.state.Sections} onClick={this.OnbuttonClick} />
           
            </div>
         );
    }
}

/*Functional components*/

function DisplaySections(params)
{
    let arr=params.param;
    return(
        <div className="Section-options">
           { arr.map((item)=>(Section(item, params.onClick)))}
        </div>
    );
}

function Section(item, onClick)
{
    let arj=item;
    return(
        <button className="Section" onClick={() => onClick(item)}>
            {item.name}
            {console.log(item.name + "Before click " +item.open)}
            {item.open && (AddDropDownItem(item.name))}
        </button>
    );
}
```

This way, your `Section` will called the `onClick` function passed to it from the props of `DisplaySections` which is actually referring to the `OnbuttonClick` function present inside the `IntroBar`.

Editing your setState code

```
OnbuttonClick = item => {
    console.log(item) 
    this.setState(previousState => ({
        Sections: previousState.Sections.map((section) => {
            if (section.name == item.name) return { name: item.name, open: !item.open };
            else return section;
        }),
    }))  
)
```

Comment: Would that also require binding the `OnbuttonClick` in the IntroBar constructor? eg. `this.OnbuttonClick = this.OnbuttonClick.bind(this);`

Comment: @CallumMorrisson In React Components, if you define a function using `arrow syntax`, your function is automatically bound. If you use traditional syntax like `function some()`, then you have tp bind it yourself.

Comment: Oh right cool, yeah I didn't notice the arrow syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @Nishant Well that was a better solution than using window.global. Thanks for recommending it. I can call the onlick event but the problem still remains. Item that I am passing in OnbuttonClick is still not updating. Infact on console it appears undefined

Comment: That item is infact from an array of objects in state and when I am passing one indexed element of the array it shows to be undefined on the console. If you could look at the code and recommend a solution that would be a big help

Comment: @NishantReddy I have copied my entire JSX file. Filters and DisplayFilters are not the concerns and I think I am messing the setState function. But still the item is put on console before the setState call. It should not have been undefined. Kindly take a look.

Comment: @CuriousBoy In your code you have written `onClick={this.OnbuttonClick}/*stateparam={this.state.open}`. What is this stateparam ? seems like a mistake during copy pasting.

Comment: They are commented. I was trying few other things before this.

Comment: In your code, you have written `<button className="Section" onClick={(item)=>onClick(item)}>`. But it should be `<button className="Section" onClick={() => onClick(item)}>`.

Comment: Also try to make a sample using http://codesandbox.io/ and share it here.

Comment: @NisanthReddy Yup. That was a mistake. One more thing if you could take a look at my setState method. Does that look right to you? Or am I doing another mistake. Cause it is still not working but the onclick is calling and the item elements are there. And also if you could briefly explain when should we pass the parameters to arrow functions? Like the mistake you pointed out in last comment of yours.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE HELP AND TIME BRO. YOU ARE ONE PRO HERE :)

Comment: @CuriousBoy updated my answer. I have added the setState code at the end. Check it out.

Comment: You are an angel. GOD BLESS YOU. Please recommend some good learning resources for react. As I am fairly new to it.

Comment: @CuriousBoy I would suggest going through the entire tutorial at https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html. It is very helpful. Also look into Javascript ES6 tutorials to learn advanced javascript concepts. With these 2, you should be able to tackle any situation.

Comment: @CuriousBoy Also do accept the answer, if it finally works :)

Comment: Thank You very Much bro. It did work. I was on Eid holidays so I didnt open up.

Comment: No worries. Hope you had a good celebration. :)